# A question about URL Rewrite in .NET

Tags: c#, url-rewriting, rewritepath

The real url is http://www.example.com/site.aspx?site=google.com
i want to the rewrite result more friendly.
like this: http://www.example.com/google.com
in C# code, i don't want to use third-party lib
only use RewritePath method or some code

Comment: Which "RewritePath" method are you talking about?

Comment: May I strongly suggest that you choose something other than xxx.com for your example domain name?  Unless you're advertising their... um... services.  Example.com is usually a safe bet.

Comment: you're using asp.net? Why don't you just create a route that includes `/google.com` instead of using that rewriting stuff in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand all of your requirements, but why couldn't you simply to a string.Replace(), or a regular expression if you could have other parameters in your query string as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are [some examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=url%20rewrite%20in%20c#) about how to rewrite, [including this one](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/network/web-URL-aspnet2-csharp.aspx).

You could also [download the source code](https://github.com/sethyates/urlrewriter) of [URL Rewriter](http://urlrewriter.net/) and see how the author does it.

Personally, I'm very satisfied with using URL Rewriter (binaries) in several of my projects.